# Wilhelm Gesenius' vowel pointing of the tetragrammaton YHWH

Tags: reference-request, tetragrammaton

Is there a writing of Wilhelm Gesenius in which he discusses the vowel pointing of the Tetragrammaton that produces the English transliteration "Yahweh"?  Does someone have a URL for it?

Comment: You can find the entry for יְהֹוָה in his lexicon [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H3068&t=KJV).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what we are about.  *This is not a comment on the quality of your post, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Answer (score 5):

He discusses the tetragrammaton at several places in the grammar.<sup>1</sup> In [§102m](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar_(1910_Kautzsch-Cowley_edition).djvu/324) he includes the vowel pointing *patach*-*šĕwă*-*sĕgōl* that leads to our English “Yahweh”. That is: יַהְוֶה‎. Elsewhere throughout the grammar he either uses the unpointed יהוה or the Masoretic יְהוָֹה (*šĕwă'*-*ḥōlem*-*qāmeṣ*; that is, the vowels of אֲדֹנָי *ʾădōnāy* <sup>2</sup>). The relationship between these forms and the nature of [*qere perpetuum*](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/9174/3555) is explained in [§17c](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar_(1910_Kautzsch-Cowley_edition).djvu/90).

As noted in [a comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42725/wilhelm-gesenius-vowel-pointing-of-the-tetragrammaton-yhwh#comment117538_42725), [Gesenius’ lexicon](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewchaldeelex00geseuoft#page/337/mode/1up)<sup>3</sup>  also includes an entry for the tetragrammaton with discussion of the historical vocalization. He lists several possilibilities including *pataḥ*-*ḥaṭef pataḥ*-*ḥōlem* (something like *yahăwōh*) by analogy with  יַעֲקֹב (*yaʿăqōb*, Jacob), consistent with some ancient Greek writings indicating that the Hebrew God was ΙΑΩ (something like *iaō*). He also discusses some support for the vowels having been *šĕwă'*-*ḥōlem*-*qāmeṣ* (the Masoretic *kĕtîb* by way of which comes the Western “Jehovah”) and finally discusses the *patach*-*šĕwă*-*sĕgōl* (יַהְוֶה - *yahweh*), which is supported by the pointing of certain abbreviations for the divine name.

---

<sub>1. Gesenius-Kautzsch-Cowley, [*Gesenius' Hebrew Grammar*](https://archive.org/details/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft) (2nd edn; Clarendon Press, 1910).</sub>

<sub>2. Almost. Just in case anyone is looking too carefully, though ... the first vowel looks different (simple *šĕwă* in י׳ rather than *ḥăṭep̄  páṯaḥ* in *ădōnāy*), but these are related and the change is virtually required by the consonants.</sub>

<sub>3. [*Gesenius’s Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures.*](https://archive.org/details/GeseniusHebrewChaldeeLexiconOldTestamentScriptures.tregelles.1857.24) Translated by Samuel Prideaux Tregelles. (Bagster and Sons, 1857).</sub>